# Refer External Resources in ANT build file

Tags: java, xml, ant, build.xml

I have an ant build file that is present on server 10.X.X.1 and in this build file I want to refer SOA_HOME (`/home/oracle/Middleware/ORACLE_SOA1`) location that is present on some other server 10.X.X.2.

Is there any way i can access this directory in ant file.

**Details :** 
`/home/oracle/Middleware/ORACLE_SOA1/bin` directory contains an XML (`ant-sca-package.xml`) file that i want to read in my build.xml

I can't copy that (`ant-sca-package.xml`) on server 10.X.X.1 , as this file depends on other lot of resources.

Any pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My first choice would be to use the [scp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) task to copy the entire directory from the other machine into your build.  That requires that the other machine is running sshd and that you have a login there.

You could just mount the other server's /home/oracle/Middleware/ORACLE_SOA1 directory using NFS or SMB, to give your build access to it, though that's obviously less portable, and I'm pretty sure those methods are less secure than scp.

NFS and SMB allow directory trees on one machine to be made available ("exported") to other machines.  Unix/Linux systems typically mount such an exported directory just as they mount a disk partition, which means the other machines effectively see it as just another partition, which means your Ant build file can access them as a regular fileset.  A Google search turned up [this](http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/how-to-configure-nfs-on-linux), [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NFS-HOWTO/server.html) and [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/set-up-easy-file-sharing-with-nfs-on-linux/) for NFS (all Linux, but NFS is present in all Unixes), and [this](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba3-HOWTO/) for Samba.

Comment: I can't copy any of the resources from there to my build machine. Its a limitation that we have.
For the second approach can you put some more light on that , any reference or tutorial to do that. - Thanks

Comment: Updated answer with some links.

Comment: Thanks for the links , I will try to implement the NFS approach. -